# Sqoop mapping all datatype as string

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, avro, amazon-emr

I'm importing a table from oracle to a s3 directory using Amazon EMR. The files are being imported as avro and Sqoop exports the avsc file with all columns as String.
Does anyone knows what to do to Sqoop map the correct datatype ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `--map-column-java` to map to the appropriate data type. For hive you can use `--map-column-hive`

Comment: But shouldn't sqoop map the fields automatically?

Comment: It will. But to get the desired mapping we need to make it explicit mapping using these commands. If you are curious download the source the code and check how the mapping has been done. [https://github.com/apache/sqoop]

Comment: first, thank you very much for your help.
I'm already usign --map-column-java with date columns that are being translated to long to translate to string, but all the others columns (NUMBER, VARCHAR2) are being translated to string as well, they all go as STRING(255).
I'm using as avro-datafile and ORAOOP and I'd like to only translate the date datetypes to STRING, all others to translate automatically.